# Getting data from user, compare it with sensor data, turn off/on power according to result of comparison

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega, atmelstudio

Help!

I'm kind of a beginner in assembly,  using atmelstudio7 working on micro controller atmega168A. 
explanation of what I want: I defined program to get the min temperature from user. And  compare it with the current temperature, if the Min temp. is lower turn off the power( RF in code).

Problem:

I don't know how to call current temperure, WHICH varible should I call to get the number of current temp.? what should I call to read the number of current temp.
The code of current temperature is here:

```
show_temp:  call append_space ;add a space character
        ldi XH, 02
        clr xl
        rcall spit16_TC72  ;read temperature sensor, answer in temp2

cvt_temp:   mov zl, temp2  ;provide reading value in temp2
        sbrc temp2, 7
        rjmp neg_temp
tpout:      clr zh  
        rcall d3ascii       
        ret
neg_temp:   neg zl ;take 2's complement
        ldi temp2, '-'  ;show negative
        call append_char  ;zl not touched
        rjmp tpout

 vbrs_temp: ldi temp, msg_temp  ;===TEMPERATURE=======
        rcall send_msg_colon_sp  ;temp
        rcall show_temp   ;temperature
        ldi temp, msg_celsius
        jmp send_msg_cr_lf  ;temperature
```

now my code for getting data from user:

```
  act101:      rcall query_check ;spit out auto response (if no parm given) 
                                                Tflag=0            
               brtc act1010rsp ;check T flag (if no parm given) Tflag=0
               sts TE_MINH, cmdhbyt
               sts TE_MINL, cmdlbyt

  act1010rsp: ldi yh, high (TE_MINH) 
              ldi yl, low (TE_MINH)

  spitatemp:    ld ZH, y+           
                ld ZL, y+                       
                call d3ascii
               call comp_MIN
               ret
```

( I have a problem with calling mintemp for the first time too, when I type mintemp( in order to get the last mintemp typed in terminal )the out put is: mintemp Z35??
where does it come from? I want to have the last typed min temp.

THE MAIN PROBLEM: comparing and turning off power if the user mintemp is lower

```
comp_MIN:   lds temp, spit16_TC72 ; current temperture.           
        lds temp2, act1010rsp ; user temperture     
        cp  temp2, temp
        brge putrfoff_
putrfoff_:  cbi PORTC, PC_PA_ONOFF
        ret
```

I don't know if spit16_TC72 is correct for calling to read the current temp or not and where is the user typed min temp?  calling act1010rsp is correct?
why turn off ( putrfoff_) the power does not work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> THE MAIN PROBLEM: comparing and turning off power if the user mintemp is lower

The problem in comp_MIN is the branch. Either if it's taken or not, the instruction 'vbi PORTC, PC_PA_ONOFF' is executed (fallthrough)

```
comp_MIN:   lds temp, spit16_TC72 ; current temperture.           
        lds temp2, act1010rsp ; user temperture     
        cp  temp2, temp
        brge putrfoff_
putrfoff_:  cbi PORTC, PC_PA_ONOFF
        ret
```

you can fix this e.g. like this:

```
comp_MIN:   lds temp, spit16_TC72 ; current temperture.           
        lds temp2, act1010rsp ; user temperture     
        cp  temp2, temp
        brlt no_change_
        cbi PORTC, PC_PA_ONOFF
 no_change_: ret
```

> I don't know how to call current temperure, WHICH varible should I call to get the number of current temp.? what should I call to read the number of current temp.

reading your code, I'd say

```
rcall spit16_TC72  ;read temperature sensor, answer in temp2
```

but this for sure can better re answered by the guy you copied the code from, since he seems to know the setup and the circuit. we can only guess that

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still does not work.

Comment: and we'll not be able to help you ANY further with just this (incomplete) snippet you gave us. As I said, you better ask the guy who gave you that code